# The relationship between force and potential energy

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, potential-energy

Assumptions:

no air resistance

a constant value of $g$.

only force acting on a dropped particle is the force of gravity.

A particle dropped would accelerate with constant $a$. Velocity would keep increasing, and therefore $dU/dx$ would be a decreasing value.

$F = -dU/dx,$ so if my logic is correct that means that $F$ should be an increasing value. But we know that the force due to gravity is constant.

My only thought is that my assumption that $g$ could be constant is inherently flawed, but its blurry in my mind as to why that would be the case.

Any help clearing this up for me would be much appreciated.

Comment: The potential energy is decreasing in time, not space.   $\partial U/\partial t = 0$, but $\mathrm{d}U/\mathrm{d}t\neq 0$. In any case, $\mathrm{d}U/\mathrm{d}x=0$.  More correctly:  $\partial U/\partial x = 0$

Comment: Also to mention, $F$ here only refers to conservative force.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue at present is that you do not make a distinction between the words "increasing" and "positive", or the words "decreasing" and "negative."   So we would say (assuming that the $+x$-direction is downward) that velocity is indeed increasing and therefore that the acceleration is positive and therefore that $F$ is positive and therefore that $dU\over dx$ is negative. But if we're talking about motion relatively near the Earth's surface, say, no higher than planes fly, then we can say that it's a roughly constant negative number; it's not increasing or decreasing.

As one goes further from the Earth's surface one finds that the gravitational force decreases like $1/r^2$ where $r$ is the distance to Earth's center, and therefore that the potential energy decreases like $-1/r$, being constantly a negative number but becoming less and less negative and closer and closer to zero. Therefore as you approach the Earth (which we said was our $+x$-direction) from these much farther distance scales, we find that the force increases, which means that $dU/dx$ gets *more negative* and therefore it *decreases*. This continues roughly until one penetrates the surface of the Earth, i.e. $r < R.$ Once one penetrates one finds (assuming the Earth is homogeneous, which it's not, but just humor me with this approximation) that actually the force goes proportional to $r$ and therefore the potential goes proportional to $r^2$. This means that while the $dU/dx$ remains negative, it gets *less negative* and therefore it *increases* until it has the value $0$ at the very center, as it must have due to rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

With $\hat x$ pointing up, $U=mgx$ where $x>0$ is the height above ground.
Thus, $F=-dU/dx=-mg$ is pointing down, and constant, i.e. not increasing or decreasing in value.  Since $F=ma$ it follows that $a=-g$ with the negative sign indicating down, in accordance with that statement that $g$ is constant and the positive direction is up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction. If $U$ is decreasing at a linear rate (ie $U=a-bx$) then $F=-\frac{dU}{dx}=b $ is constant.